# Retrieve data from .rec binary file

Tags: matlab, binary, labview

The question may be naive, but answers could help me.

A measurement is recorded in binary format, with a header that contains all information about the data and the data itself (i.e. a series of doubles).

The measurement data can be exported in csv format from the application, but it takes ages.

What do you have to pay attention to when trying to read data from a binary file? Is this process even feasible using Matlab to import as an array or labview (export as .txt maybe?)

Comment: Do you know what application generated the .rec file?

Comment: Yes, it's the user interface of a displacement sensor. The file should contain an array of doubles, that are the measured displacements at the sampling rate.

Comment: hmm when I say application, I meant is it running on LabVIEW, Visual C, Matlab, etc.?  If the .rec file just contains an array of binary number of tyoe double then that would be relatively simple to cast to double assuming the delimiter is present, e.g. carriage return, comma.  Why not post some data so we know what you are dealing with?

Comment: The ultimate use is to be imported in matlab for further analysis (Fft etc..). The application that generates the .rec file is a "blackbox" that works via web interface, we can only change some settings and save recorded data in .rec file or in csv format, but as I said below if the number of samples is too high (7x10^6 or so)  .rec is the only viable option

Comment: I used matlab recently to import a similar file and also used LabVIEW too for the same file.  This may help : https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop

Comment: Just define the data type that you are reading.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binary `.rec` file format may refer to various things (audio/video encoding format of Topfield based on MPEG4-TS, proprietary audio encoding, and even MRI scanner from Phillips) ...

If it refers to MRI scanner you may find some direct reader on fileexchange: [Matlab PAR REC Reader](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38797-matlab-par-rec-reader--readparrec42-m-)

If it refer to something else, you may parse binary file header and data by yourself using the low level routine: [fread](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html)

**Edit**

Not knowing the exact file format for your recorded sensor displacement, here is dummy example with fread for reading large rec file block-by-block supposing header contains just the length of data, and that data is just a serie of double values:

```
function [] = DummyReadRec()
%[
    % Open rec file for reading
    [fid, errmsg] = fopen('dummy.rec', 'r');
    if (fid < 0), error(errmsg); end
    cuo = onCleanup(@()fclose(fid));

    % Read header (here supposing it is only an integer giving length of data)
    reclenght = fread(fid, 1, 'uint32');

    % Read data block-by-block (here supposing it is only double values)
    MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH = 512;
    blockCount = ceil(reclenght / MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH);
    for bi = 1:blockCount,

        % Will read a maximum of 'MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH' (or less if we're on the last block) 
        [recdata, siz] = fread(fid, [1 MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH], 'double');

        % Do something with this block (fft or whatever)
        offset = (bi-1)*MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH;
        position = (offset+1):(offset+siz);
        plot(position, 20*log10(abs(fft(recdata))));
        drawnow();

    end
%]
end
```

Comment: Thank you, it's somewhat clearer now. The .rec file should contain, after a header, an array of doubles, that represent the displacement measured by a sensor. The built-in user interface allows to save the .rec file and a cvs file, but the exporting csv file fails if the number of samples is too big, while .rec saving is always possible

Comment: @AlessandroDelPizzo I edited my post with some `fread` example for reading large file block-by-block ... of coourse is file is shorter so data can fit in memory, your can just read everything in one step ... to be adapted upon your exact file header/data content ...

Comment: I've used  
fileID = fopen('rec.rec','r','n','UTF-8');
[recdata, siz] = fread(fileID, [1, 200000], '*char');

This way, recdata contains all the header. the last characters I can read are "Main Frame", starting from which there should be the doubles array, am I right?

PS: I used utf-8 because what I get has some meaning, and at a certain point I read Encoding: UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

The answer is going to depend on the format of your binary file and how large it is.

I have done many conversion of various binary files all with differing layouts.  If the file will fit into memory then you can just use [fread](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html) as long as you know the layout of the binary file.  Below is an example of reading a header & simple data block.  It would of course have to be modified depending on the layout of your file.  Depending on recording equipment & computer type you may also need to make use of the `machinefmt` ('ieee-le' or 'ieee-be') options of fread ... that has burned me before.

```
%Open the File for reading
fid = fopen(yourRECfile,'r');

%Read the  Header  ... your layout will be different
header.MajorRel  = fread(fid,1,'uint16'); %Major File Rev #
header.MinorRel  = fread(fid,1,'uint16'); %Minor File Rev #
header.IRIGStart = fread(fid,1,'double'); %Start time in secs
header.Flags     = fread(fid,1,'uint32'); %Flags

%Read everything else from there until end of file as a series of doubles.
data = fread(fid,inf,'double'); 
fclose(fid);
```

If the file does not fit into memory you will either need to process it in blocks or look into using [memmapfile](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/memmapfile.html).